# How to make a PokemonGo esque map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I need help finding resources to develop a PokemonGo-esque map, as in a 3d map from a 3rd person but not birds eye view, like 45degree angle camera. Is there any existing library or techniques to transform a map to this perspective? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapbox will fit your needs as you can do all of those types of things. You will be able to change the colors of the streets and land to something that you would like. You can also tilt the map so that your view is from an angle. Then you can use their SDK to place your map in whatever browser or app you want.

You just need to go to Mapbox and create a new style. `Mapbox -> Home -> New Style`

Comment: Found it on their site! Thanks.https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/set-perspective/